# update subobject in mongodb with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following schema:

```
friends: [{
    user: { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User' },
    read: Boolean,
    accepted: Boolean 
}]
```

I would like to update read field. I have the following query:

```
User.update({_id: user._id, 
             "friends.$._id": {$in: data.friends}
            }, 
            { $set: { "friends.$.read": true }}, 
            false, 
            true,
            function(err, obj) 
                console.log(obj);
            }
);
```

This works fine with one document but when I have two or more documents, only the first one changes.

For example:

```
[{
    user: 'user1', 
    read: true, 
    accepted: false
 }, 
 {
    user: 'user2', 
    read: false, 
    accepted: false
 }]
```

only changed user1.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `update` command in `MongoDB` updates only one document, the first one that matches your query. If you want to update all the documents, you have to specify it by passing the option `{ multi: true }`.

I am not a `Node.js` expert, but in your example I am pretty sure that if you change the first `false` of your query to `true` (which, according to this link: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html, is the `multi` option) it's going to work. Like this:

```
User.update({_id: user._id, 
         "friends.$._id": {$in: data.friends}
        }, 
        { $set: { "friends.$.read": true }}, 
        true, 
        true,
        function(err, obj) 
            console.log(obj);
        }
);
```

Otherwise, you can try to passe directly the `multi` option in your query:

```
User.update({_id: user._id, 
         "friends.$._id": {$in: data.friends}
        }, 
        { $set: { "friends.$.read": true }}, 
        { multi: true },
        function(err, obj) 
            console.log(obj);
        }
);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It seems he's using Mongoose, while you referenced node-mongo-native doc. Well, it still applies though :)

Comment: @yaoxing Thanks for pointing that out! As I said I am not an expert but it seems I was not too far with my second query: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html ;)

Comment: Well, I guess what he means is that he needs to update every element in the field `friends`. I'm afraid that is not possible by now. See the [JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243)